# Launch AlertDialog from Handler

Tags: android

in my activity I originally used a handler to update the UI with data received from the internet. I now want to display this data inside an alertdialog instead of on the UI screen. The program works by pressing a button, gets the information and displays it on the screen. this is done by calling the necessary message for the handler. I managed to do for a Toast message and I thought the alertdialog would follow the same logic but I get the error:

```
RunTime Error: Unable to add Window -- token null is not for an application
```

Here is my code for the handler message, where the error is apparently caused (Line 84 which is the .show() method line):

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        switch( msg.what )
        {
            case DISPLAY_TOAST:
                Toast t = Toast.makeText( context,"Toast Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
                t.show();       
            break;


            case UPDATE_UI: 
                htmlData.setText( feedback );           
            break;


            case DISPLAY_ALERT_DIALOG:

                passTime = new AlertDialog.Builder( context );
                passTime.setTitle( alertDialogTitleStrg );
                passTime.setMessage( alertDialogMsgStrg );
                passTime.show();

            break;
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context object is wrong, the simplest way you can do is the following:

```
passTime = new AlertDialog.Builder( YourActivity.this );
```

greetings

Comment: Thanks it worked fine there, although I had this originally as well but it still failed...I must be going senile

Comment: sometimes strange things are going on in the developer's life ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't show an `AlertDialog` using the application context, you'll have to get a reference to your activity context and use that in your `AlertDialog` constructor.

Comment: Cheers for the answer - what you mean is basically what the previous poster is referring to right?

Comment: @Katana24 Yes, you can get the activity context with `ActivityName.this`. Dialogs are somehow tied to activities and you should always use the activity context when you create one.